# Как получить содержимое файлов полученных с помощью getExistingDirectory?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtablewidget, qlistwidget

Как можно получить содержимое файлов полученных с помощью `getExistingDirectory` и загрузить это содержимое в `tableWidget` по нажатию на соответствующий элемент в `listWidget`?

**main.py**:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import ui

class pars(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, ui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(pars, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btn_las_lib.clicked.connect(self.las_lib)
        self.las_list.itemClicked.connect(self.las_tab)

        self.csv_rows = []

    def las_lib(self):
        self.dir = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self.las_list, " ")
        if self.dir:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.dir):
                for file_name in files:
                    if file_name.endswith(".txt"):
                        self.las_list.addItem(file_name)

    def las_tab(self):
        self.las_data.clear()
        self.las_data.clear()

        self.las_data.setColumnCount(3)
        cur_row = self.las_list.currentRow()

if __name__ =="__main__":
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
ui = pars()
ui.show.()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ui.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(484, 343)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.btn_las_lib = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_las_lib.setObjectName("btn_las_lib")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.btn_las_lib)
        self.las_list = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.las_list.setObjectName("las_list")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.las_list)
        self.las_data = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.las_data.setObjectName("las_data")
        self.las_data.setColumnCount(0)
        self.las_data.setRowCount(0)
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.las_data)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 484, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_las_lib.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

Файлы:
01:

```
a, b, c
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
```

02:

```
a, b, c
3, 2, 1
3, 2, 1
3, 2, 1
3, 2, 1
3, 2, 1
```

03:

```
a, b, c
2, 3, 5
2, 3, 5
2, 3, 5
2, 3, 5
2, 3, 5
```

Файлы находятся в под каталогах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файлы, которые вы показываете - это **`CSV`** - текстовый формат, предназначенный для представления табличных данных.

**01.csv**

```
Hello, csv, file
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
1, 2, 3
```

Я отметил для вас строки, в которые внес изменения, чтобы вы получили желаемый результат.

```
import sys
import os
import pandas as pd                                                            # !!! + pandas

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

# from ui import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(484, 343)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.formLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.formLayout.setObjectName("formLayout")
        self.btn_las_lib = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_las_lib.setObjectName("btn_las_lib")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(0, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.btn_las_lib)
        self.las_list = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.las_list.setObjectName("las_list")
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.LabelRole, self.las_list)
        self.las_data = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.las_data.setObjectName("las_data")
        self.las_data.setColumnCount(0)
        self.las_data.setRowCount(0)
        self.formLayout.setWidget(1, QtWidgets.QFormLayout.FieldRole, self.las_data)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 484, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.btn_las_lib.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
        
        
class Pars(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Pars, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.btn_las_lib.clicked.connect(self.las_lib)
        self.las_list.itemClicked.connect(self.las_tab)

#        self.csv_rows = []

    def las_lib(self):
        self.dir = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self.las_list, 
            "Выбрать папку",                                                    # +++ 
            "Test/folder/"                                                      # +++ 
        )
        if self.dir:
            for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.dir):
                for file_name in files:
# ----------------------------------------> vvv
                    if file_name.endswith(".csv"):                              # ??? ".txt"
#                        self.las_list.addItem(file_name)
# ------------------------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
                        self.las_list.addItem(os.path.join(root, file_name))    # !!!

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
# ------------------> vvvv
    def las_tab(self, item):                                                    # +++ 
    
        f_name = item.text()
        _data = pd.read_csv(f_name)
        numColomn = 0 
        if numColomn == 0:
            numRows = len(_data.index)
        else:
            numRows = numColomn
            
        self.las_data.setColumnCount(len(_data.columns))
        self.las_data.setRowCount(numRows)
        self.las_data.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(_data.columns)  

        for i in range(numRows):
            for j in range(len(_data.columns)):
                self.las_data.setItem(i, j, 
                    QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(_data.iat[i, j])))

        self.las_data.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.las_data.resizeRowsToContents()            
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Pars()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @modniyTIGR что не так?

Comment: все так, немного только не то что я хотел) Спасибо!